# Angular 2 Have method print out svg polygon points

Tags: angular

I have a simple method which prints out some svg polygon points:

```
printOutSVGFormat() {
        var andrew = "200,10 250,190 160,210";
        return andrew;
    }
```

And the template is shown below:

```
<div class="svgWalkableArea">
            <svg height="210" width="500">
              <polygon [points]="printOutSVGFormat()" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
            </svg>
          </div>
```

However Angular errors with the following code:

```
Can't bind to 'points' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:polygon'
```

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `attr.points`

```
<polygon [attr.points]="printOutSVGFormat()" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
```